# angular-google-maps - How to use ng-repeat directive in ui-gmap-window tag?

Tags: angularjs, google-maps

I need to use a ng-repeat directive into an ui-gmap-window item but it does not work.

```
<ui-gmap-google-map center="search.map.center" zoom="search.map.zoom" draggable="true" >
<ui-gmap-marker ng-repeat="position in search.positions" idKey="position.name" coords='position.coords' options="title='{{position.name}}'" >
    <ui-gmap-window ng-show="position.show" onclick="position.show = !position.show" closeClick="'closeClick'" ng-cloak isIconVisibleOnClick='true' >
        <div ng-controller="InfoWindowInMarkerController">
            <h4>{{position.name}}</h4>
            <div ng-if="! position.isGroup">
              <!-- code that display the information of a unique member -->
            </div>
            <div ng-else>

                <p>{{position.isGroup ? "Veuillez voir ci-dessous les personnes associées en utilisant les filtres de recherche pour limiter à la ville souhaitée" : ""}}</p>
                <!-- below the ng-repeat that didn't work -->
                <div ng-repeat="p in position.persons">{{p}}</div>

              <br><br><br><br>
              <br>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ui-gmap-window>
    <!--<marker-label content="position.name" anchor="22 0" class="marker-labels"/>-->
</ui-gmap-marker>
```

Could you please tell me how to do ?

Please find below a link to the plunker that illustrate my problem : 
http://plnkr.co/edit/EinFCPEsdhS94ssPHEF2?p=preview

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am facing the exact same problem. Any clues?